# Admin best practice

Tags: windows, admin, standards

thanks for reading. This might not be the best forum for this, bit I'm struggling for help elsewhere and I know there's some very knowledgeable people on here.

I'm about to undertaker an install of some metrology software onto a measuring machine.
IT have refused to do it as they don't understand it, but obviously the task needs admin access, which I don't have.
They are however happy to remote on and type their admin password in when needed.

The question is, what is best practice?
Should they be blindly putting in their password without knowing the process and what it involves?
Is there anything in any standards that cover such things?

To me if a task requires admin access it should be performed by a component administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with you in the fact that the task should really be performed by an Administrator, however, I guess you can't really change how they operate.

From personal experience, I would say that most sysadmins would just remote in any way.